# How to handle Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" using ampersand-rest-collection?

Tags: rest, ampersand-collection

Trying to request cors request with code:

```
export default Collection.extend({
  model: person,
  url () {
    return 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/person/'
  },

  ajaxConfig: function () {
        return {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http//:127.0.0.1:3000'
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            }
        };
    },
})
```

I'm sending request with **http//:127.0.0.1:3000** but if use ***** i still get error below

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/person/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How to handle this kind of request?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than your Collection sending the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http//:127.0.0.1:3000'` in its request headers, your server at http://127.0.0.1:5000 needs to send it in its response headers to the pre-flight request.

If you can give some details about the server setup, I can help you to figure out how to add the header to the response.